# ¿Cómo puedo correr comandos de Django sin entrar al contenedor Docker?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

Realice el quickstart django-docker https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/ y estoy intentando correr los comandos de Django (makemigrations, migrate, startapp, etc...) sin tener que entrar al contenedor donde esta corriendo Django o corre `docker-compose run web python manage.py ...` . Alguna idea?

Comment: La única opción para ejecutar un comando sin entrar al contenedor es `docker run`. ¿Por que esto no te sirve esto o cual es el caso que necesitas solucionar?

Comment: Al trabajar con Laravel es posible correr comandos `php artisan` sin necesidad de ingresar al contenedor ni anteponer `doker-compose run ...` o `docker exec`. Tenia la esperanza de que con Django se pueda hacer lo mismo.

Comment: Creo que puedes entrar en el modo interactivo como te pusieron en una respuesta, y así evitarte correr el comando tan largo, recuerda que los contenedores te ofrecen un sistema operativo independiente, como una máquina virtual, por lo que podrías correr un comando como: `docker-compose exec web /bin/bash` y de esta forma estarías en modo interactivo dentro del contenedor, como si te conectaras a una sesión ssh y de esta forma evitar escribir comandos largos, solo los que siempre usas: `./manage.py runserver` o `./manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: @leonelibarra No me queda totalmente claro, ¿Lo que buscas es una forma más cómoda de ejecutar los comandos, o es otro el motivo?

Comment: @SaúlHormazábal en resumidas cuentas seria eso. Hace poco comence a trabajar con Laravel y me parecio curioso que pueda correr comandos sin tener que entrar al cantenedor.Y estoy caso seguro de que con Django se puede hacer los mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como Django está corriendo dentro del contenedor, los comandos se han de ejecutar dentro del contenedor, pero para evitar tener que entrar dentro, o escribir `docker-compose run web python manage.py ...` cada vez, se pueden crear scripts dentro del proyecto.

Por ejemplo, se puede crear el siguiente script en `d/manage`:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose run --rm web python manage "$@"
```

`d` es el nombre de la carpeta donde los suelo agrupar, pero se puede usar cualquier otro nombre (ej. `bin`), o simplemente tenerlos en el root del proyecto.

Una vez el script tenga permiso de ejecución (`chmod a+x d/manage`) se pueden lanzar comandos así: `d/manage startapp ...`

Comment: Es la mejor opción que vi hasta ahora. Por otra parte estoy experimentando otra alternativa que se me ocurrió utilizando un entorno virtual y un archivo settings que extienda del settings.py original.

Comment: @leonelibarra si no te he entendido mal esto te obligará a tener instalada la versión de python y las dependencias en el host, no? Esto es una de las cosas que se pretende evitar usando `docker`, ya que en el momento que puedes lanzar `php artisan` des de tu host sin entrar al container es porque tienes `php` y las dependencias instaladas en tu ordenador. Si lo lanzas todo dentro del contenedor, lo único que _necesitarías_ tener instalado seria `docker`.

Comment: Exactamente. Por el momento a nivel local tener instalado python virtualenv docker docker-compose me parece bien. En producción si me parece fundamental solo usar docker.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el comando exec:

`docker exec -ti {dockerId} [comando]`

Esto lo que hace es ejecutar el `comando` en modo interactivo dentro del Dockerfile indicado. También puedes utilizar el nombre asociado a ese Docker.

Comment: Si conocía esa opción pero no es lo que estoy buscando ya que lo que yo quiero es no tener que escribir comandos adicionales como `docker exec -it ...` o `docker-compose run ...`. Además de que tendría que estar recordando o fiajandome el nombre del contenedor .

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo combinando varias funcionalidades de Docker.

**Docker multistage build**

Para instalar las dependencias que tengas del proyecto en una imagen temporal
Luego tomar las dependencias o librerias y con eso tener una imagen lista de tu app

docker build -t nombre-de-tu-image .

```
FROM python:3.5-slim as artifact
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/


FROM python:3.5-slim
COPY --from=artifact /code/ /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
EXPOSE 8000
```

**Usar volúmenes**

Para que las dependencias se descarguen en tu máquina local y para levantar siempre la aplicación con el código actualizado.

Para descargar dependencias

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app python:3.5-slim pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Para levantar app

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app python:3.5-slim python manage.py runserver
```